# Php, file_put_contents within body tag

Tags: php, dom, file-put-contents

Im using Dom parser to extract content from html page within body tag something like:

```
$html = file_get_contents('index.php');

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$body = "";
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $body .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
echo $body;
```

but now I need to put modified $body variable back into index.php file  and replace content within  tag. Can I do that with `file_put_contents()`

Comment: Use [DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php).

Comment: @syck that will not work. I dont want to replace whole file just body content.

Comment: And what happens to the rest of the file?

Comment: As for file_put_contents(), what is unclear? Did you try it? If not, why not?

Comment: the rest of the file will remain the same, I just need to replace content within <body> </body> tags